# Firefox doesn't show javascript errors on AJAX 'threads'?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function `test_fn` that's called two ways:

(a) From an `onclick` attribute of a button; or (b) from the `success` function of a jQuery AJAX call, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  'POST',
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        test_fn();
    }
});
```

I've noticed that my Firefox (3.6.17 on Linux) Error Console doesn't seem to show me *any* javascript errors that arise in code called by the AJAX success function.  Whereas it does show errors, as usual, in code that's run by a GUI action.

For example, if I have my test function `test_fn` defined as follows:

```
function test_fn() {
    blah
}
```

I'll see the obvious javascript error reported on the Error Console when `test_fn` is invoked via a click on the button, but NOT when my code does the (successful) AJAX call and calls `test_fn` that way.

I've looked around the web and haven't seen anything along the lines of "AJAX 'threads' don't log their javascript errors" or anything like that.  A lot of my javascript is executed within an AJAX callback ... I'm wondering if this behaviour has sneaked in somewhere/somehow.  I'm a bit rattled by it; when one's Javascript silently fails it's hard to track down where without an error message or line number.

Can anyone offer any help or advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type:  'POST',
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        test_fn();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       // Aw Snap... Check textStatus maybe?
    }
});
```

Comment: I do have an error function to pick up an AJAX error, yes.  AJAX isn't getting an error; it's successfully fetching the data from the server and calling the anonymous 'success' function, which in turn calls test_fn(), which incurs a javascript error ... but that error isn't shown in the Firefox Error Console.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the whole thing in a `try...catch` statement and log it if there's an exception. That can get a little tedious, so you may want to make a function which returns a function which wraps a function for you:

```
function wrap(func) {
    return function wrapped() {
        try {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
        }catch(ex) {
            if(console&&console.error) {
                console.error(ex);
            }else{
                alert(ex);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: wrap(function(data) {
        // Test it by generating an error by calling a number.
        (1)();
    })
});
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to do something like that (thank you for the elegant wrapper) if my AJAX-called javascript continues to fail silently.  But it would be nice if the Error Console showed the error like it does for GUI-invoked calls.

Comment: @Brad: I don't know if you're using Firebug or not, but if you aren't, try it! The code in my post checks for `console.error`. If it's not there, it'll do an `alert`. I don't know if Firefox has `console` without Firebug, but with Firebug, it should be there and display similarly (although likely not identically) to an error outside of an AJAX request.

Comment: icktoofay - using your wrapper the error will be logged to the Firebug console - if it's open.  If Firebug isn't open then I'll get the alert (so it seems Firefox doesn't have a 'console' without Firebug).  So far so good.  Weird thing is, if I open up Firebug, run the test, I see the error logged.  After I close firebug, though ... the error isn't logged by the alert, it just silently fails.  I have to reload the page to see the alerts again.  Trapping the errors is fine but it's a pain when one has to do it, when the standard Firefox Error Console shows some errors but not others.  Argh!